# Using go-swagger, how to have the @description reference an external Markdown file?

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-swagger, redoc

So I am using the above two technologies to autogenerate my `swagger.yaml` file that then is read by Redoc and served to the clients. This is the step in my makefile:

```bash
swag init -g internal/delivery/rest/router.go --output swagger/ --outputTypes yaml
```

Then in my Redoc I simply reference `swagger.yaml` and everything works like charm.

But I have one problem. In my `@description` annotation for the API I have something like this:

```
   // @description "This is a description!"
```

But I want that this description actually come from a Markdown file. I know that if I manually add:

```yaml
   description:
     $ref: 'description.md'
```

to my `swagger.yaml` file it works perfectly. But the thing is I can only hardcode the string in the annotations. I tried this in my annotation:

```
// @description file://description.md
```

But it literally generates this in my YAML file:

```yaml
description: 'file://description.md'
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Hello, please check this document [Using markdown descriptions](https://github.com/swaggo/swag#using-markdown-descriptions), and [swag cli](https://github.com/swaggo/swag#swag-cli) `--markdownFiles value, --md value`

Comment: @Trock Yeah! I did. But that will literally embedd the markdown inside the swagger.yaml file. When there is no need for that. Redoc can read the reference just fine. I want to know how to reference it, notcopy pasting one file inside the other.